# Pass a copy of GKSession object from one view to another

Tags: objective-c, object, memory-management

I want to pass a GKSession object from one view controller to another. Actually I want to pass a copy of the object, but as I read the particular object is not copyable.

So a declaration like this returns error :

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) GKSession *currentSession;
```

Is there any other way to do that...?

Thanks in advance....